# Npm start not working after running create-react-app ONLY in Documents directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-start

I've been battling this issue all day and still cannot figure out what I am missing. I've always created my projects under the Documents directory on my computer but I've started getting the following error when trying to start a project after using create-react-app.

```
my-app@0.1.0 start C:\Users\{user}\Documents\B&R Fun\nginx_test_deploy\my-app

react-scripts start

'R' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\{user}\Documents\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-app@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-30T21_02_14_553Z-debug.log
```

Interestingly, running the exact same commands on my desktop creates an app without errors. Is there some configuration I'm missing that could impact apps created under the 'Documents' folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clear and re-install node_modules. You can do this by running the following command.

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install && npm start
```

Also, upgrade to a later version of [node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm).

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename `B&R Fun` folder to avoid ampersand there. It seems that `&` breaks everything. See [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8121)